# How to minimize video Player in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have a home controller where movies list is displayed like Youtube and when i click on movie it plays in full screen I also want to play movie in minimized view and background should be home controller and can select any movie, same as youtube.

Comment: This is a requirement, not a question/problem. Please show what you have tried and what issues you are facing with it

Comment: I have created  a uiview on home controller when I back from full screen, I am passing the url to uiview but it's not playing on uivew.

Comment: Refer this link - https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-set-up-video-streaming-in-your-app-with-avplayer-7dc21bb82f3

Comment: No option to play video in minimized view. as we play cideo in youtube in full screen and when we minimize it video still plays in small view.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a requirement, not a question.
There's a video series by a youtuber who implemented the same which you require right now.
[Check out this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0dzCUj1L5JGKdVUtA5xds1zcyzsz7HLj)

Comment: I have seen the videos, he is trying to show this type of implementation but has not implemented.